# PyTorch Lightning: Multiple scalars (e.g. train and valid loss) in same Tensorboard graph

Tags: pytorch-lightning

With PyTorch Tensorboard I can log my train and valid loss in a single Tensorboard graph like this:

```
writer = torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter()

for i in range(1, 100):
    writer.add_scalars('loss', {'train': 1 / i}, i)

for i in range(1, 100):
    writer.add_scalars('loss', {'valid': 2 / i}, i)
```

[image]

**How can I achieve the same with Pytorch Lightning's default Tensorboard logger?**

```
def training_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_idx: int) -> Tensor:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.log('loss/train', loss.item())  # creates separate graph

    return loss

def validation_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_idx: int) -> None:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.log('loss/valid', loss.item(), on_step=True)  # creates separate graph
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doc describe it as `self.logger.experiment.some_tensorboard_function()` where some_tensorboard_function is the provided functions from tensorboard so for your question you want to use

```
self.logger.experiment.add_scalars()
```

Tensorboard doc for pytorch-lightning can be found [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.loggers.TensorBoardLogger.html#pytorch_lightning.loggers.TensorBoardLogger)

Comment: Yeah, already feared that I could not use `self.log()`. Was hoping I had missed something as logging train/valid loss together seems like a pretty basic use case to me.

Comment: I agree, this seems like a very common use case that self.log does not cover. Hope someone would fill this gap soon.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify the above the code then in Pytorch Lightning would be:

```
def training_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_idx: int) -> Tensor:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.logger.experiment.add_scalars('loss', {'train': loss},self.global_step) 

    return loss

def validation_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_idx: int) -> None:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.logger.experiment.add_scalars('loss', {'valid': loss},self.global_step)
```